# How to call a jQuery function AFTER html and content (images) finished loading..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to do at all..?

The goal of this is to load a heavy Flash movie, after the images, text, and contents of my page is finished loading...

Any solutions..?

**More details:
The Flash movie (a music mp3) is loaded in a frame (menuFrame) with the menu.  The content (that needs to be loaded first) is in another frame (contentFrame)...**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(window).load(function() {
    // this code runs after the page finished loading
});
```

Comment: What if the content that needs to be loaded first is in another frame..?  Is it possible..?   What would replace WINDOW in your example..?

Comment: A frame in a frameset...  The website was build with frames, menu is in one frame and content in another...

Comment: Oh, gosh... frames. I don't even remember what those are :) You should put that information in the title of your question...

Answer (score 2):

`$(window).load()` is exactly what you are looking for. The event fires when the whole page, i.e. the DOM *plus* all image resources, has loaded. [From the docs](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/):

> The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

window.onload

or Jquery version:

$(window).load()

Answer (score 0):

A frame cannot "look into" another frame, only access its parent (frame-->frameset, iframe-->parentDocument). So you cannot implicitly wait for another frame to load. If you control the other frame's content, then you should publish an event here, like `window.callMeWhenLoadIsDone=function(){ alert('hey'); };` and in the other frame you would "reach out" to call it like `$(window).load(function(){ window.parent.callMeWhenLoadIsDone(); })`. This assumes you are the code of the main page in a page/iframe setup or the frameset code in a frameset/childFrame setup. And of course note that framesets are deprecated. ;)